# How to dynamically append an array value to a select option that contains at least one attribute

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

This is my attempt, it's part of an ajax request function:

```
$("#theSelectID").append($('<option>title=' + ArrayValue[i] + '</option>'));
```

The ArrayValue[i] is the part of the JSON object that I need to grab and use as a jQuery UI Tooltip when the user hovers the newly appended  element.

Comment: I'm probably being dumb but I don't get the point about "contains at least one attribute".

Comment: my problem is how to include the title attribute to the newly appended <option> element

Comment: Attributes go inside the opening tag, not inside the contents.

Comment: You also need text to go between the `<option>` and `</option>` tags. Should this be the same or different from the title attribute? If different, what should it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't adding a title attribute to the option, for that it would be like this:

```
$("#theSelectID").append($('<option title="' + ArrayValue[i] + '">Value</option>'));
```

You could also do this:

```
$("#theSelectID").append($('<option>').attr('title',ArrayValue[i]));
```